# SSIS - Query value from database to provide Excel export filename

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am building a data export SSIS package using SQL Server Data Tools, I would like to deploy this across several different SQL Servers.

To keep the package standard across all SQL Servers, I need to somehow use a variable in the package to identify the Excel filename and path, which is in a format similar to the example below:

D:\Export\Files\CUSTOMERNAME\Monthly_Export.xlsx

For each deployment the folder structure and filename would be the same, only the customer name would change.

I can easily retrieve the customer name via SQL query, but I don't know if/how I can use this as a variable.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: I can assist, sure, but what is it you aren't sure how to do? Why not use a parameter on your package?

Comment: Project deployment model and parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Use a variable to store the "CustomerName" value. Use an expression for your Excel output path. You may also want to delay validation and/or pre-populate that "CustomerName" variable with something that would never be used for an actual customer.